# Error Using realloc-Problem when reallocating char* with size=3

Tags: c, realloc

Im doing a school project and as i was coding it i got this error about invalid next size.
Ill leave here a short version of what happened in my main code.
The program seems to break as soon as i get to the final realloc when size=3
Thank you

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    int main(){
    char * arga[7];
    arga[1]="2018-11-12";
        arga[2]="2018-11-13";
        arga[3]="EUR";  
        arga[4]="BRL";
        arga[5]="JPY";
        arga[6]="GBP";
        int argc=7;

    int i=4;
        int size=2;
        //int indexes = (sizeof(arga)/sizeof(arga[0]))+1;
        char**moedas=malloc(size*sizeof(char*));
        moedas[0]=arga[3];

        while(i<argc){

            moedas[i-3]=arga[i];
            moedas=realloc(moedas,size*sizeof(char*));
            size++;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How much memory do you think line `malloc(size * sizeof(char *))` allocates?

Comment: when size=3,24 bytes? @StaceyGirl

Comment: When `size=3`, probably, but in your case `size` is 0.

Comment: Ohh i see what you are talking,about moedas[0] right? yeah my mistake however if size only went up to 2 it worked without any problem @StaceyGirl

Comment: So what is your problem then?

Comment: @StaceyGirl As i said i went on debug mode and checked that if size=3 the program stops with the error realloc invalid size in the line moedas=realloc(moedas,size*sizeof(char*));

Comment: As I said, you are allocating zero-sized memory block and then use it.

Comment: @StaceyGirl Changed the code now,and still have that problem  on size=3 :x

Comment: You still have the same bug at `moedas[i-3]=arga[i];`

Comment: @StaceyGirl yeah sorry,still happens with size initialized at 2

Comment: Yeah because you have one more bug. You still not allocating enough memory - `size` is incremented AFTER `realloc`

Comment: yes sorry for all the trouble,its working now,thank you very much for the patience @StaceyGirl

Comment: OT: for robust code, when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc()`:  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: OT: regarding: `while(i<argc)`  This would be much better written as: `for( i=3; i<argc; i++ )`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert an appropriate space inside parens, inside braces, inside brackets, around c operators, after semicolons, after commas

Answer (score 1):

you immediately write out of the allocated memory :

```
int size=0;
char**moedas=malloc(size*sizeof(char*));
moedas[0]=arga[3];
```

because index 0 is out of the malloc(0)

then in the first loop of the *while* when *i* is 4 in the line

```
moedas[i-3]=arga[i]
```

because index 1 is also out of malloc(0)

---

After your edit initializing *size* to 1 the first error disappear (index 0 legal) but not the second where the index is 1

Comment: i changed a bit the code now because the first thing you pointed out was one wrong thing but not where the error was apeearing
and what you mean on your secound sentece?

Comment: @JoaoBarata I edited my answer, still considering your first version of the question

Comment: @JoaoBarata with size initialized to 1 the second error will be still present, only the index 0 is allowed not index 1

Comment: yeah sorry xD
Still happens if i start the size at 2

Comment: @JoaoBarata with initial value to 2 there is no more invalid memory access

Comment: Yeah i understand that now and was doing a terrible mistake however i still get the error realloc() invalid size

Comment: Idk anyways i just put the size++ line before the realloc and got no more erros,thanks